# django guardian importerror but other examples work

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-guardian

First off, I am new to both django and python.

I am working on an existing project that is using django-guardian 1.3.2. I verified the server this app is deployed is also using 1.3.2 via `pip list`.

I am trying to understand the cause of an exception.

There are existing admin.py files, which load just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin

from devices import models


class SomeModelAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
  pass


admin.site.register(models.SomeModel, SomeModelAdmin)
```

I added mine, and this also works (on my machine).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin


from django.contrib import admin
from common import models


class MyModel1Admin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(models.MyModel1, MyModel1Admin)


class MyModel2Admin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(models.MyModel2, MyModel2Admin)
```

We deployed the app, and now it fails to start with the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 187, in **call**
>       self.load_middleware()   File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 47, in load_middleware
>       mw_instance = mw_class()   File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py",
>   line 24, in **init**
>       for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:   File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
>   line 365, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
>   line 360, in urlconf_module
>       self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
>   line 40, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "./sites/zpanel/urls.py", line 19, in 
>       admin.autodiscover()   File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/**init**.py",
>   line 29, in autodiscover
>       import_module('%s.admin' % app)   File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
>   line 40, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "./common/admin.py", line 3, in 
>       from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin ImportError: No module named admin

The server is running python 2.7.6, and I am using 2.7.10. I wouldn't think this is an issue since other admin.py files import from guardina.admin just fine.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'sites.this_app',
    'notifications.email',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
    'guardian',
    'my_stuff',
    'existing_ones'
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'south',
    'djangular',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'djrill',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_extensions',
    'parler',
    'watson',
    'baldr',
)
```

Comment: Have you checked which version of guardian is installed in production?

Comment: And are you using different settings for development and production?

Comment: @zanderle the version of guardian matches. I don't think i'm using different settings. You mean a `settings.py` file, right?

Comment: I mean `settings.py` yes. You ran `pip freeze` to check the version? Could you also paste your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @zanderle I ran `pip list`.

Comment: @zanderle updated with the INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a directory called `guardian` in the same directory as my `admin.py` file. This directory isn't in the source (anymore), nor is it on my local machine. I guess it was some residue from some deployment long ago...